# Python Selenium : TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not WebElement

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, gspread

Hello I'm trying to perform a for loop for different elements tr, each of them with td with information to extract, when I do the loop, It return me the error: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not WebElement

```
lines = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//[@id='DataTables_Table_0']/tbody/tr")

    for x in lines:

    Date = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("Date")
    record.acell(getNextRow(), Date[x].text)
#             The error is here    ^^^


    Country = driver.find_element_by_class_name("Country")
    record.acell(getNextRow(), Country[x].text)


    League = driver.find_element_by_class_name("Region")
    record.acell(getNextRow(), League[x].text)


    HomeT = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("CompanyY")
    record.acell(getNextRow(), HomeT[x].text)


    VisitT = driver.find_element_by_class_name("CompanyV")
    record.acell(getNextRow(), Visit[x].text)
```

This give me this error message: `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not WebElement`

How can I perform a loop each tr and extract the td info?

I need some help.

**EDIT**
at "for" statment, using range(len(lines)) instead of lines does loop work properly.

Comment: Can you provide us with the full error stack ? Or tell us at what line the error occurs. You can edit your question.

Comment: that's the full error message:, line 89, in <module>
    record.acell(getNextRow(), Date[x].text)
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not WebElement"

Comment: Ok and which line is line 89 ?

Comment: record.acell(getNextRow(), Date[x].text)

Comment: Maybe use “for x in range(len(lines)):” instead?

Comment: @Tim with "range(len(lines))" works. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

once you have all the rows:

```
rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//[@id='DataTables_Table_0']/tbody/tr")
```

... just iterate over them and find the td's they contain:

```
for row in rows:
    elem = row.find_element_by_tag_name('td')
    print(elem.text)
```